# How do I make my desktop computer wireless?

Tags: wireless-router, desktop

I want to make my desktop computer wireless, how exactly can I do this? Do I have to install a  wireless card in my PC? Is there another way?

I've read I can use a usb wireless adaptor. Are these difficult to install?

Comment: No they are not difficult to install. buy one, and follow the instructions in the manual. Personally I've never seen the value of wifi on a desktop. if its going to sit in one place, you might as well run a line and get the full bandwidth of your gigabit network, instead of crippling your connection.

Comment: Three reasons for desktop WiFi: I have a dodgy internet connection, but interruptions never last long enough for ISP to find and repair, so next-door's WiFi is a useful standby; I also use next-door's WiFi when I want to test my network from outside my intranet; and I occasionally need to move the the desktop to another room for a while. I use a USB adapter, available for around £10 in UK, but if you are short of USB ports you can use a cheap router in _AP Client_ mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireless USB adapter is your best bet if youre looking for simplicity.

Just plug it in and follow the instructions in the install disc. Very easy.

http://www.newegg.com/Wireless-Adapters/SubCategory/ID-31

Comment: Cheers Kirk! Appreciate the response.